# Convert a DataGridView Cell type at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My datagridview has a checkbox column that is only valid for some records in the data it is displaying. For the records for which a checkbox is not valid I wish to display nothing - a blank textbox for example.

Thus i need to dynamically change the cell type at run time from a checkbox cell to a textbox cell. I cannot simply change the column data type as the column needs to have a mix of textbox and checkbox cell types.

So far I have the code below.

```
 this.deviceList1.DeviceGrid[colIndex, rowIndex] = new KryptonDataGridViewTextBoxCell()
 this.deviceList1.DeviceGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
```

Howver this generates a DataGridView data error:

> System.FormatException: Formatted
>   value of the cell has a wrong type.

Comment: Ah, Solution is to ensure that the Value property is given an appropriate value. I.e it needs to be set to a string value.                                        this.deviceList1.DeviceGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Value = "";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorted it. Simple really. Solution is to ensure that the Value property is given an appropriate value. I.e it needs to be set to a string value.

```
this.deviceList1.DeviceGrid[colIndex, rowIndex] =  new KryptonDataGridViewTextBoxCell()
this.deviceList1.DeviceGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
this.deviceList1.DeviceGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OnPaint event handler for the cell in question and draw a blank square over the control. It's kind of hacky and I'm sure there are other options, but it works.